# How can I handle my array in a better way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a minigame in Discord, which collects players - creates an array out of participants and then starts to kill them one by one until only one survivor is left. However I'm having a weird problem where most of the time winner emerges, but sometimes it does not. I've been trying to figure this out, even though about making a feature out of it at first - but then again - I'd like to know where I've done the mistake. Here's the code:

```js
function StartGame(array, runner) {

  message.channel.send("**THE GAME HAS STARTED**");

  let amountOfDays = array.length - 1;
  let dailyDeaths = [];

  for (let MainLoop = 0; MainLoop < amountOfDays; MainLoop++) {

    let rando = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

    dailyDeaths.push(rando);

    let newarray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] != rando) {
        newarray.push(array[i]);
      }
    }

    array = newarray;
  }

  let winnerOfTheRace = array.join(", ");
  if (winnerOfTheRace) {
    runner.send("**runner debug** - Everything calculated (winner is going to be **" + winnerOfTheRace + "**). Launching the game.");
  } else {
    runner.send("**runner debug** - Everything calculated (no winner - this is the error here.).");
  }
  
  LoopThroughTheGame(dailyDeaths, winnerOfTheRace);

  return;
}
```

The `.join(",")` in `winnerOfTheRace` setting is if I want to set up multiple winners in the future. But at the moment I expect it to return only one name. And it usually does. Randomly doesn't. What am I doing wrong? :D

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand but at first glance it looks like you don't have defence against duplicate deaths - is there anything stopping the random function picking the same player twice? And if it does 'kill' that player twice is it possible you don't have a winner because a day didn't actually reduce the right number of players?

Comment: Your array might be having multiple same values, so when you do (array[i] != rando) , there might be multiple elements matching this condition. 
You should work with array indexes rather than array values when pushing to new array

Comment: I have made duplicates impossible - so the bug is not there. After following LoopThroughTheGame you can figure out the winner but for some reason winnerOfTheRace sometimes results empty